# Finding all primary solutions of $2 \cos3x=1$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all the primary solution in the interval$[0,2\pi]$
>   $$2 \cos3x=1$$

I started by isolating the variable first dividing each side by factors that didn't contain the variable.

My answers ended up to be...
$$
x=\ \frac{\pi}{9},
     \pm \frac{2\pi}{3}, \text{ and }
     \pm \frac{5\pi}{3}.
$$
Are there any others?

Comment: $-\frac\pi9$ is not in $[0,2\pi]$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to solve the equation $2\cos(3x) = 1$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.
\begin{align*}
2\cos(3x) & = 1\\
\cos(3x) & = \frac{1}{2}\\
\cos(3x) & = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)
\end{align*}

Consider the following diagram.

[image: symmetry_of_sinusoidal_functions]

By symmetry, $\cos\theta = \cos\varphi$ if $\theta = \pm \varphi$.  Since any angle coterminal with these angles will have the same cosine, $\cos\theta = \cos\varphi$ implies
$$\theta = \pm \varphi + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Hence, $\cos(3x) = \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right) \implies$
\begin{align*}
3x & = \frac{\pi}{3} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z} & 3x & = -\frac{\pi}{3} + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}\\
x & = \frac{\pi}{9} + \frac{2k\pi}{3}, k \in \mathbb{Z} & x & = -\frac{\pi}{9} + \frac{2m\pi}{3}, m \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
We wish to find the solutions in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.
$$0 \leq \frac{\pi}{9} + \frac{2k\pi}{3} \leq 2\pi \implies 0 \leq k \leq 2 \implies x = \frac{\pi}{9}, \frac{7\pi}{9}, \frac{13\pi}{9}$$
$$0 \leq -\frac{\pi}{9} + \frac{2m\pi}{3} \leq 2\pi \implies 1 \leq m \leq 3 \implies x = \frac{5\pi}{9}, \frac{11\pi}{9}, \frac{17\pi}{9}$$

Comment: This picture is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Well, $\cos y = 1/2$ has 2 solutions $y = \pm 2\pi/3$, so you need to solve
$$
3x = \pm \frac{2\pi}{3},
$$
but remember you need $0 \le x \le 2\pi$ so you are likely better off solving $3x = 2\pi - 2\pi/3$ instead of $3x = -2\pi/3$...

Answer (score 1):

$2\cos 3x=1$

so $\cos 3x = 1/3$ and $x = \pm \frac{\pi}{9} + \frac{2}{3}k \cdot \pi$ where $k$ is a natural number since solutions are in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.
$k = 0$, $x = \pi/9$,

$k = 1$,  $x = \pm \dfrac{\pi}{9} + \dfrac{2}{3} \cdot \pi = \dfrac{7}{9} \pi$ or $\dfrac{5}{9}\pi$

$k = 2$,  $x = \pm \dfrac{\pi}{9} + \dfrac{4}{3} \cdot \pi = \dfrac{13}{9}\pi$ or $\dfrac{11}{9}\pi$

$k = 3$,  $x = -\dfrac{\pi}{9} + 2 \cdot \pi = \dfrac{17}{9}\pi$

Comment: So there are 3 more solutions?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this website.  Also, you meant $\cos 3x = \frac{1}{\color{red}{2}}$.